# Grails/CreateCriteria - compare two lists

Tags: grails, createcriteria

By using the CreateCriteria, I want to compare two lists and check if there are at least one element in `groups` present in `users`.
Is there something like `eq` to perform that?

**Domain**

```
class User {
    String login
    static hasMany = [groups = String]
} 

class Project {
    String  name
    static hasMany = [users = User]
}
```

**CreateCriteria**

```
def UserInstance = User.get(1)

def idList =  Project.createCriteria().list () {

    projections { distinct ( "id" )
        property("name")
        property("id")
    }

    eq("users.login", UserInstance.groups) //check if there are at least one element in groups list present in users list.  
    order("name","desc")

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use [inList(String propertyName, Collection c)](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.2.x/api/grails/orm/HibernateCriteriaBuilder.html#inList(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Collection)) like this:

```
def UserInstance = User.get(1)

def idList =  Project.withCriteria {

    projections { 
        distinct("id")
        property("name")
        property("id")
    }

    users {
        inList("login", UserInstance.groups)
    }

    order("name","desc")
}
```